# JavaFX 2.2 FXML Validated TextField

Tags: javafx-2, validation, textfield, fxml

I improved my previous implementation of TextField validation, this time making a true Custom Control with real-time validation using binding. It is usable with FXML without the need of more Java code.

```
import javafx.beans.binding.BooleanBinding;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.effect.BlurType;
import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow;
import javafx.scene.effect.Effect;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

/**
 * <p>
 * TextField with regex-based real-time input validation.
 * JavaFX 2 and FXML compatible. </p>
 * <p>
 * FXML code example:<div>
 *  {@code <ValidatedTextField fx:id="validatedTextField" minLength="1" maxLength="1" mask="^[0-9]*$" />}
 * </div>
 * </p>
 * 
 * @author 82300009
 */
public final class ValidatedTextField extends TextField {

    private final BooleanProperty invalid = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
    private final StringProperty mask;
    private final IntegerProperty minLength;
    private final IntegerProperty maxLength;

    private Effect invalidEffect = new DropShadow(BlurType.GAUSSIAN, Color.RED, 4, 0.0, 0, 0);

    public ValidatedTextField() {
        super();
        this.mask = new SimpleStringProperty(".");
        this.minLength = new SimpleIntegerProperty(-1);
        this.maxLength = new SimpleIntegerProperty(-1);

        bind();
    }

    public ValidatedTextField(String mask, int minLength, int maxLength, boolean nullable) {
        this(mask, minLength, maxLength, nullable, null);
    }

    public ValidatedTextField(String mask, int minLength, int maxLength, boolean nullable, String string) {
        super(string);
        this.mask = new SimpleStringProperty(mask);
        this.minLength = new SimpleIntegerProperty(minLength);
        this.maxLength = new SimpleIntegerProperty(maxLength);

        bind();
    }

    public ReadOnlyBooleanProperty invalidProperty() {
        return invalid;
    }

    public ReadOnlyStringProperty maskProperty() {
        return mask;
    }

    public ReadOnlyIntegerProperty minLengthProperty() {
        return minLength;
    }

    public ReadOnlyIntegerProperty maxLengthProperty() {
        return maxLength;
    }

    public boolean getInvalid() {
        return invalid.get();
    }

    public String getMask() {
        return mask.get();
    }

    public void setMask(String mask) {
        this.mask.set(mask);
    }

    public int getMinLength() {
        return minLength.get();
    }

    public void setMinLength(int minLength) {
        this.minLength.set(minLength);
    }

    public int getMaxLength() {
        return maxLength.get();
    }

    public void setMaxLength(int maxLength) {
        this.maxLength.set(maxLength);
    }

    public Effect getInvalidEffect() {
        return this.invalidEffect;
    }

    public void setInvalidEffect(Effect effect) {
        this.invalidEffect = effect;
    }

    private void bind() {
        this.invalid.bind(maskCheck().or(minLengthCheck()));

        this.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> ov, String t, String t1) {
                if (textProperty().get().length() > maxLength.get()) {
                    setText(t);
                }
            }
        });

        this.invalid.addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean t, Boolean t1) {
                if (t ^ t1) {
                    if (t1) {
//                        setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold; -fx-text-fill: red;");
                        setEffect(invalidEffect);
                    } else {
//                        setStyle("-fx-font-weight: normal; -fx-text-fill: inherit;");
                        setEffect(null);
                    }
                }

            }
        });
    }

    private BooleanBinding maskCheck() {
        return new BooleanBinding() {
            {
                super.bind(textProperty(), mask);
            }

            @Override
            protected boolean computeValue() {
                return !textProperty().get().matches(mask.get());
            }
        };
    }

    private BooleanBinding minLengthCheck() {
        return new BooleanBinding() {
            {
                super.bind(textProperty(), minLength);
            }

            @Override
            protected boolean computeValue() {
                return textProperty().get().length() < minLength.get();
            }
        };
    }

    private BooleanBinding maxLengthCheck() {
        return new BooleanBinding() {
            {
                super.bind(textProperty(), maxLength);
            }

            @Override
            protected boolean computeValue() {
                return textProperty().get().length() > maxLength.get();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

There is still, however, a trivial point about the "invalid" graphical effect.
As you can see here:

```
this.invalid.addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean t, Boolean t1) {
                if (t ^ t1) {
                    if (t1) {
//                        setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold; -fx-text-fill: red;");
                        setEffect(invalidEffect);
                    } else {
//                        setStyle("-fx-font-weight: normal; -fx-text-fill: inherit;");
                        setEffect(null);
                    }
                }

            }
        });
```

I tried with the setStyle but using **-fx-font-weight: inherit;** breaks the code (don't why since it should be its default value). Injecting a StyleClass doesn't work since I can't revert it when invalid is false.

Any clue? It is of course possible to detach the inner listener and attach another outside with other effects (f.i. showing a green tick sign instead of altering the TextField effect).

You are free to use the code if you mind :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always revert a style by removing it from the list of style classes i.e.

```
node.getStyleClass().remove("my-style");
```

Comment: I'm now using it but it seems rather slow... furthermore it does not apply pseudo-state :invalid.
Shouldn't it read invalid variable value and apply pseudostate?

Comment: I have used the add/remove style technique and didn't find it slow, you may need to measure if this part of code is really the problem.  You need to implement a Skin to have a state other than those supplied.  See https://github.com/shemnon/DeckControl/tree/master/src/main/java/com/github/shemnon/deckcontrol/skin for some code examples.

Comment: I guessed so. In fact I'm now watching the JavaOne 2011 tutorial about creating custom controls (http://www.parleys.com/#st=5&id=2789&sl=35) to implement a proper redistributable control. I'll take a look at that github too, thanks a lot!